# Laravel - PHP Artisan Tinker: How to view all tables in sqlite database

Tags: sqlite, laravel, laravel-artisan

I have a Laravel project and I have a sqlite database. I want to view all the tables in the database in `php artisan tinker`.

I have tried this `$tables = DB::select('SHOW TABLES');` but it throws this error `Illuminate\Database\QueryException with message 'SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1 near "SHOW": syntax error (SQL: SHOW TABLES)'`

Comment: Although the above $tables line works for me, can you try `DB::select(DB::raw('SHOW TABLES'));`?

Comment: @OsamaSayed Thanks but it returns this error, Illuminate\Database\QueryException with message 'SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1 near "SHOW": syntax error (SQL: SHOW TABLES)'

Comment: Does any DB query run like a normal `select * from some_table`? I mean I just wanna make sure that the connection to the Database works fine!

Comment: That does not work but if I run a query like App\Note::all(); it does work

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is the answer, and it can be found here, https://www.sqlite.org/faq.html#q7

```
DB::select("SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='table' ORDER BY name;")
```

Thanks to @GwynBleidd on Laracasts for finding the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I know that is a old question but i was looking for this, and found a different solution if someone else need, according to Laravel syntax, here it is::

```
DB::table('sqlite_master')->select('name')->where('type', 'table')->orderBy('name')->get()
```

This way you can perform a query search, or if you want you can return a Collection array with a list of the name of tables.

```
   $this->DB
        ->table('sqlite_master')
        ->select('name')
        ->where('type', 'table')
        ->orderBy('name')  
        ->get()
        ->pluck('name');
```